# Google play showing some devices as incompatible

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play, android-market-filtering

Following are the features that my app is using:

```
Screen layouts: SMALL NORMAL LARGE XLARGE

android.hardware.location
android.hardware.screen.portrait
android.hardware.telephony
android.hardware.touchscreen
```

But google play is showing galaxy tab2 and some other tabs as incompatible. Can anyone tell what could be the reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for the `android.hardware.telephony` feature, which means that the device must have the ability to make calls over the cell network. As both the Nexus 7 and the Galaxy Tab 2 are tablets, they do not have this feature.

If this is not a definite requirement for your app, make your `<uses-feature>` tag as follows:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: I understand nexus 7 doesn't have this feature.. but galaxy tab 2 has voice calling feature..why is google play blocking it..

Comment: Only one version of the tab has voice calling. the others don't, and will be excluded.